# Firebase reach limit

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-storage

What happen to my app if the firebase reach the limit, and the firebase storage?. I'm new in firebase and android development can you help me? thank you and advances

I create a simple app like todo list and what if the firebase reach the limit what happen to my app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your Firebase project reaches its quota limit, some Firebase services may stop functioning until you either reduce usage or upgrade your Firebase plan. The specific impact on your app will depend on which Firebase services you are using and how you are using them.

For example, if you are using Firebase Realtime Database and you exceed the free quota limit of 1 GB of stored data, your app will no longer be able to write data to the database. Similarly, if you are using Firebase Storage and you exceed the free quota limit of 5 GB of stored data, your app will no longer be able to upload new files to the storage bucket.

There are a few ways to prevent your app from being impacted by Firebase quota limits.

Comment: The much higher answer rate and the verboseness suggest this has been generated by [ChatGPT_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned).

Answer (score 2):

From the Firebase [FAQ](https://firebase.google.com/support/faq/#pricing-exceed-3):

> **What happens if I exceed Spark plan upload, download or storage limits for Cloud Storage?**
>
> When you exceed limits for Cloud Storage in a project on the Spark plan, the result depends on the type of limit that you exceed:
>
> - If you exceed the GB stored limit, you will not be able to store any more data in that project unless you remove some of the data stored or upgrade to a plan that provides more storage space, or unlimited storage space.
> - If you exceed the GB downloaded limit, your app will not be able to download more data until the next day (starting at midnight, US Pacific Time), unless you upgrade to a plan with less restrictive limits, or with no limits.
> - If you exceed the upload or download operations limit, your app will not be able to upload or download more data until the next day (starting at midnight, US Pacific Time), unless you upgrade to a plan with less restrictive limits, or with no limits.